# javascript concat() method adds newline randomly

Tags: javascript, string, checkbox

I'm writing a JS code that reads the checkboxes in a particular , checks if they're selected, and if yes, appends their value to a string. This is the code that I have:

```
    var checkboxArr = document.querySelectorAll('#div_name input[type="checkbox"]');
    var str="";
    for(var i =0; i< checkboxArr.length;i++){
        var cb = checkboxArr[i];
        if(cb.checked){
            var newVal=cb.value;
            str=str.concat(newVal);
            str=str.concat(",");
        }
    }
    alert(str);
```

The string that I get is:

```
value1
,value2
,value3
```

How are these newlines coming in the string ?

Also, the occurance of these newlines is random - sometimes they appear, sometimes I get the desired string.

I also tried combining the concat() calls into 1 statement, and I used the `+=` operator as well, but no luck.

Any guidance is earnestly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your HTML?

Comment: check the page source in the browser (usually Ctrl+U in good browsers) - look at the `value="whatever"` for the check boxes ... is the last `"` on a new line? also, I suspect the values are actually not that short and you are simply misinterpreting the alert (also, you have no trailing `,` in the sample output, which you would surely get given your code) - use console.log instead of alert, see if the same mysterious new lines appear in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all you need. Use js right :D

```
var checkboxArr = document.querySelectorAll('#div_name input[type="checkbox"]');
var str = [];

checkboxArr.forEach(function(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) str.push(cb.value);
});      

alert(str.join(', '));
```

and if you still have the same result check your `html` code. It seems like you have line break right after your value in checkbox

Comment: `filter` and `map` would be nicer.. ;)

Comment: yep, maybe. but `forEach` is always easier for noobies

Comment: `concat - is array method, not string method` - then his code wouldn't work **at all** - according to your logic, [String#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) doesn't exist, but it works, and adds a newline for your trouble

Comment: I agree that string.concat is not what you want to use - but your answer would make no difference to the result given the same input

Comment: "use js right" ... exactly - `var str = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkb‌​ox"]'), cb => cb.checked).map(cb => cb.value).join();`

Comment: thanks, I know how 2 use `call` method or what U meaning :) have a nice day. Add `', '` in your `join`

Answer (score 1):

check implementation with ES6, not sure why you are getting `new line`,

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function(){
var checkboxArr = document.querySelectorAll('#div_name input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
   var res = Array.from(checkboxArr).map(cb => cb.value.trim()).join(',')
   console.log(res)
}
```

```html
<div id="div_name">
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb_1" />    
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb_2" />    
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb_3" />    
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb_4" />    
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb_5" />    
</div>
<button id="btn">Check</button>
```